# Mongodb aggregation retrieve a field in a stage and use it in another stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assume we have documents like below:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "stock_item" : "almonds", warehouse: "B", "instock" : 120 },
{ "_id" : 2, "stock_item" : "pecans", warehouse: "A", "instock" : 80 },
{ "_id" : 3, "stock_item" : "almonds", warehouse: "B", "instock" : 60 },
{ "_id" : 4, "stock_item" : "cookies", warehouse: "B", "instock" : 40 },
{ "_id" : 5, "stock_item" : "cookies", warehouse: "A", "instock" : 80 }
```

The input is **{stock_item: "almonds"}** but we want to :

1. find all documents that have {stock_item: "almonds"}
2. retrieve the warehouse field of all documents returned in part 1
3. return all documents that their warehouse field is included in part 2 as final result

So the final result would be like below because documents 1 and 3 have **{stock_item: "almonds"}** condition and both of them have **{warehouse: "B"}** so in result we want to return all documents that have **{warehouse : "B"}** :

```
{ "_id" : 1, "stock_item" : "almonds", warehouse: "B", "instock" : 120 },
{ "_id" : 3, "stock_item" : "almonds", warehouse: "B", "instock" : 60 },
{ "_id" : 4, "stock_item" : "cookies", warehouse: "B", "instock" : 40 }
```

I can do this by using two find queries respectively, but I was wondering How can I do this with mongodb aggregation in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course two queries seem to be the most straightforward way and that's what I would recommend. On the other hand this question is interesting so **experimentally** you can achieve what you want using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

The idea is that you can grab one document matching your filering condition and then run self-lookup to get the rest of them knowing the content of that first document.

You also need [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) in order to reshape the output (lookup will return an array of nested subdocuments).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { stock_item: "almonds" }
    },
    { 
        $limit: 1 
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection",
            let: { si: "$stock_item", w: "$warehouse" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $or: [ { $eq: [ "$$si", "$stock_item" ] }, { $eq: [ "$$w", "$warehouse" ] } ] } } }
            ],
            as: "documents"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$documents"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$documents"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5UlUnp_vJTi)

Comment: Works fine if you're sure that all "almonds" are in the same warehouse. Otherwise, not.

Comment: I think you should put "as" instead of "in" in lookup. In that case the query works fine.

Comment: @dzdmmtf that's correct, I have changed it in Mongo Playground but copied old code. Thanks!

Comment: What about multiple warehouses for 'almonds"?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a 'select(1) in select(2)'.

Use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to first find your select(2) value, then use it in a $in condition (will work with multiple warehouses as select(2) result)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      inCond: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$stock_item",
            warehouses: {
              "$addToSet": "$warehouse"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            _id: "almonds"
          }
        }
      ],
      docs: []
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "docs": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$docs",
          "as": "doc",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$doc.warehouse",
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$inCond.warehouses",
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$docs"
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test the solution here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lymUbFrauZ9)